# Changing default browser in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, browser

I currently have Firefox set to be my default browser. I would like to change it to Cruz because if Firefox isn't currently open it takes almost a minute to load. Plus it's rather sluggish at times.

How do I change the default browser?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easiest way is to use Safari's preferences, this will let you change it to any browser on the system (not just Safari)

Comment: The most annoying preference location on OS X.

Comment: WTF. Stupid stupid stupid. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: This isn't technically a Safari preference, Safari just allows you to change it (stored in `com.apple.LaunchServices.plist`). So there is sane design underneath, just not in the UI

Answer (score 1):

`System Preferences` -> `General` -> `Default web browser`

...or `⌘ space` and start typing `Default web browser`. Glad it's now decoupled from Safari.