# HTML link in a PDF file is opened in Chrome instead of Safari

Tags: macos, file-association

I have a PDF with inside a link to a URL. This URL points to another PDF file, like  `http://Myurl.com/myfile.pdf`.

I can't find the option to make Safari open `myfile.pdf` instead of Chrome.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Which one is your default browser?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing default browser in Mac OS X](http://superuser.com/questions/112605/changing-default-browser-in-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2573/os_x_how_to_change_default_application_to_open_file_type/), you can:

1. Ctrl-click on the file
2. Click Get Info

   [image]
3. Under Open With pick the app that you want to become the default

   [image]
4. Click the Change All button
5. Confirm your decision

Comment: Since many browsers can show PDF, I'm not sure this applies to PDFs opened using a browser (through clicking a link in either a web page, or in a PDF document, rather than opening from disk directly)?

Comment: @Arjan if you do this to an .html file, that should change the global default for that type of file. The issue here is that your OS is calling the app associated with .html files and that seems to be chrome and not safari. Doing the above should change the default to safari.

Comment: @Arjan  if you do this to a .pdf file, that should change the global default for that type of file. The issue here is that your OS is calling the app associated with .pdf files and that seems to be chrome and not safari. Doing the above should change the default to safari and so open them within the browser.

Comment: Nope. I just tested the steps above, and [they don't change the way Chrome opens HTTP PDF links](http://stlab.adobe.com/wiki/images/d/d3/Test.pdf), though Preview is set as my default application for local files. Using [a PDF that uses that very same HTTP link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1732174/pdf-with-http-link.pdf), the HTTP link is also opened in Chrome (which is my default browser), even when that PDF is open in Preview.

Comment: Or, are you suggesting to *always* use Safari to open PDF files, not only PDF files that are on the web? (Like by selecting Safari instead of Preview in the image in your answer.) I feel that's horrible; why would you want to open *local* files in a browser too?

Comment: @Arjan I'm not sure what you're trying to do. If you have a local PDF file open in your PDF viewer and click on a link, it should open the default browser. You can change the default browser by changing the program associated with `.html` files. If the link is to a local PDF file, it should open in the default PDF viewer which you can set in the same way.

Comment: I don't think one can change the default browser by changing how `.html` files are opened. (Instead, simply use a browser's preferences to set itself as the default browser, or use Safari's preferences to choose *any* browser. Both ways will also change the way HTTP and HTTPS protocols are handled, not just some file extension.) (But all said, the question is vague, and some part was not even visible.)